# Android RecyclerView horizontal GridLayoutManager with decoration bug?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

guys
When I use horizontal RecyclerView ItemDecoration I encounter some problems, I want to achieve different decoration height but horizontal recyclerview decoration height is always the same, pictures and code are below, I used the same code in vertical GridLayoutManger is effective, I saw the source code should be measured when the horizontal recyclerview has special processing, this is normal?

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWPJ3.jpg)

```
class MainItemDecoration : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {

    private val space20 = (Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density * 20).toInt()

    override fun getItemOffsets(
        outRect: Rect, view: View, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State
    ) {
    val lp = view.layoutParams as GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams

    outRect.left = space20
    outRect.right = space20
        when (lp.spanIndex) {
            0 -> {
                outRect.bottom = 0
            }
            1 -> {
                outRect.bottom = space20
            }
            2 -> {
                outRect.bottom = space20 * 2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

----- MainActivity----

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val recyclerView: RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view)
        recyclerView.apply {
            layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 3, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
            adapter = MainAdapter()
            addItemDecoration(MainItemDecoration())
        }
    }
}
```

--- xml-------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        tools:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_main"
        tools:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:spanCount="3" />

</FrameLayout>
```

--- item ----

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        tools:text="123" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Your problem is not clear . you might wanna [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67030598/edit) your question and explain the current and expected output .

Comment: @ADM my problem is recyclerview with horizontal gridlayoutManager & ItemDecoration not expect,the vertical space always same,but You can see I control the vertical spacing